# Delphi DatetimePicker not recording date

Tags: delphi, datetimepicker

On exiting my Delphi form, if the Datetimepicker numbers are being typed in by the user, the date (DateTimePicker1.Date) value is not changed in the following scenario: 1.)Windows date format is MM/dd/yy, 2.)the default date value in the DateTimePicker has a 2 digit day as '11' for May 11th (e.g. "05/11/19"), 3) There is an "OK" BitBtn on the form and it is the default button, 4).The user types a 2 in the area for day and presses the "Enter" key.
Code for "OK" button:

`procedure TMyForm.BitBtn1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  testDate: TDateTime;
begin
  MessageDlg('My date is '+DateToStr(DateTimePicker1.Date),mtInformation,[mbOK],0);
end;`

All the conditions above, unfortunately common for many of my users, are needed to make this fail. For example if the user types "02" for May 2nd, fine, or if the user **clicks** on the OK button fine, or if the user arrows away from the day entry or tabs out of the date entry field, then they can press "enter" and the default runs the button fine.

I have tried many properties on the form and button to no avail. Bet work around I have so far is to make the the "OK" button not the default button, but I should be able to keep this user friendly??

Comment: What does "recording" a datetime means?

Comment: Sounds more like a problem with how you are getting the date from the `TDateTimePicker`, rather than a problem with the picker itself.  Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates your problem.

Comment: Anything that changes the focus works here. E.g. `SetFocus` just before the message dialog.

Comment: Not for me. I tried combinations of SetFocus, DateTimePicker1.Refresh, and SetFocusedControl. User still has to click on the default button. My best work around now is to not assign any default button, but to Underline the text etc. and write FormKeyDown for the "enter' key to run the OK button. That works, but the OK button style not as good.

Comment: So it looks like the more specific BitBtn1.SetFocus, right at the beginning of BitBtn1.Click may work. Have to test some more here.

Comment: Well, @SertacAkyuz, that was right on! I tried various combos, not just "SetFocusl", but BitBtn1.SetFocus, at the beginning of BitBtn.Click. So you post that as an answer so i can vote for it?

Comment: @Scott, you go ahead please.. :)

Answer (score 1):

The single digit in a DateTimePicker is not enough to have the 2 digits needed be set into the date variable with many Windows date formats. This credit should go to @SertekAkyuz for saying to just add a "SetFocus" before accessing the changed date. It was not just "SetFocus", but BitBtn1.SetFocus Or some other component, at the beginning of BitBtn.Click.